# Changing Route attribute value dynamically in ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, routes

I am looking for a way to grammatically change the value of Route attribute.

I have a scenario where the api route should be either :

1. `[Route("api/v1/[Controller]")]` or
2. `[Route("api/xyz/v1/[Controller]")]`

based on whether I am running it in debug mode or not.

```
[Route("api/v1/[Controller]")]
[ApiController]  
public class MyController : BaseController
{
}
```

I tried adding a variable in Base Controller but realized that I can't access it in Route attribute.

Comment: just use both route attributes on the controller

Comment: You can't change the value of a Attribute after compilation, however, the [ConditionalAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute?view=netframework-4.8) exists, you may be able to work something out with it

Answer (score 4):

You cannot change the value of an attribute after compilation, as attributes are compile time constants. That's also why you can't use a variable from you controller class as a parameter (unless it is `const`)

Instead, you can use [preprocessor directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/) to do this like so

```cs
#if DEBUG
[Route("api/v1/[Controller]")]
#else
[Route("api/xyz/v1/[Controller]")]
#endif
```

(You may want to change it around to `if RELEASE` and also change to routes)

Comment: Though I must agree that it may work but is there by any chance a neater solution?

Comment: The neatest solution would be to not need different routes in different circumstances, but there are reasons for everything. A somewhat neater solution may be to do what Kiksen said and not use attribute routing and instead specify the routes in the `Startup.cs`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your startup.cs

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
   routes.MapRoute("default", "api/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Simply make a if statement for debug.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
   routes.MapRoute("default", "api/xyz/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Or UseControllers or whatever you are using.